# Calling external logout within Classic ASP

Tags: ajax, json, iframe, asp-classic, backend

basically what I am looking for is something like this;

I have a link on a classic asp site that calls an .ASPX file, which in turn sets a bunch of user credentials from Sessions variables and then re-directs to a third party vendor hosted site, dirty I know but nothing can be done about it now.

so the process is;
1. Loads classic asp page with link to .ASPX page
2. Clicks link, sends to .aspx page
3. .ASPX sets required data and .Send() to third party vendor application

the issue is that if the user doesn't "logout" of the third party site and goes back in under a new username, the first username credentials stay set.  What I want to do is on the .asp page before the user clicks to go to the third party vendor app call the vendor apps Logout page in the background.  I was thinking of using an iFrame, but an iFrame just displays the logout page, it won't actually execute the code that is associated with it.

Any help is greatly appreciated,
Nick G

Answer (score 0):

Your Iframe method should work if you got the server side code correct.  Two things to bear in mind though.

First, session variables are specific to domains, so if your pages are available via multiple domains and the src attribute of an Iframe is different to the one from which the user accessed your site to start with then your session data will not be recognised.  This may even apply if one url includes the "www" and the other doesn't - I've never tested this

Second, Classic ASP files and ASP.net files can't share session variables, you need separate sets of variables for each set of pages.  If you need to synchronise the two sets a common hack is to use a 0px by 0px iframe, eg

```
<iframe height="0" width="0" src="dotnetpage.aspx?userid=<%=Session("userid")&loggedin=<%=Session("loggedin")" />
```

Obviously dotnetpage.aspx would contain code to set the querystring values as session variables, and you can have a classic page receiving a querystring from a .net page

Comment: The issue that I am having with the <iframe> stuff is that an iframe is basically treated like another browser window/session being loaded within my site.  What I am doing is trying to access a third party vendors LogOut functionality on my .asp site, and the only way I could think of was iframes, but they don't actually run the functionality built into the site they display, not with the stored cookies/sessions anyway.  thank you for your answer though, i appreciate the help

Comment: Hmm, it might be worth you while to add an ajax tag to your question, it might offer more possibilities than iframes.  Also, Does your third party vendor offer any kind of integration support?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever solution you come up with along these lines will only work as long as it takes for this third party vendor to realize they have a gaping security hole in their site and decide to close it.

One should **never** be able to log someone out of another system by injecting a hidden iframe in their page, for example.  This is a form of a CSRF vulnerability and indicates a sloppy security posture by the other site.

I would certainly consider another approach.

Comment: I agree with you completely, honestly I am just not sure what other approach to take.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a better approach with classic asp and just included the url as an  and it seems to be working correctly.